# Unwanted blank lines and semicolons in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
    x $\longleftarrow$ 0\tcc*[r]{initialize x}
    \uIf(\tcc*[r]{if comment}){condition 1}{
        x $\longleftarrow$ 1\tcc*[r]{set x as 1}
        }
    \uElseIf(\tcc*[r]{else comment}){condition 2}{
        x $\longleftarrow$ 2\;
        }
    \Else{
        x $\longleftarrow$ 3\tcc*[r]{set x as 3}
    }
\caption{First algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

which produces this pdf:
[image]
Where the two marked semicolons and the marked blank lines are unwanted. Can you help me what to change in the code please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `f` as optional argument for `\tcc*` instead of `r` when the comment doesn't end the line.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
    x $\longleftarrow$ 0\tcc*[r]{initialize x}
    \uIf(\tcc*[f]{if comment}){condition 1}{
        x $\longleftarrow$ 1\tcc*[r]{set x as 1}
        }
    \uElseIf(\tcc*[f]{else comment}){condition 2}{
        x $\longleftarrow$ 2\;
        }
    \Else{
        x $\longleftarrow$ 3\tcc*[r]{set x as 3}
    }
\caption{First algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

From the `algorithm2e` documentation:

> `\tcc*[r]`{right justified side comment, **ends the line** (default)}: comment “ la” C

while

> `\tcc*[f]`{right justified comment, **without end line**; useful with ”if-then-else” macros for example}: comment “ la” C